# What is the 'page lifecycle' of an ASP.NET WebForm?

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-2.0, webforms, page-lifecycle

I'm looking to get a more thorough understanding of the ASP.NET page lifecycle.  I'm in the process of building custom form controls and have found my knowledge in this area to be lacking.

Are there any resources, tutorials, etc. that you've used to better understand this area?

Are there any tools you've used to improve your knowledge in this area?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've found this chart to be fairly useful.  Provides a brief description as to what the piece is doing...
[John-Sheehan ASP.NET Life Cycle Events](http://lh4.ggpht.com/realnero/SGs-58G1jKI/AAAAAAAAAto/YgbkErfakOY/s1600-h/life%5B5%5D.jpg)

Answer (score 33):

I have this on my tack board. Helpful when your using Master pages.

1. Content page PreInit event
2. Master page controls Init event
3. Content controls Init event
4. Master page Init event
5. Content page Init event
6. Content page Load event
7. Master page Load event
8. Master page controls Load event
9. Content page controls Load event
10. Content page PreRender event
11. Master page PreRender event
12. Master page controls PreRender event
13. Content page controls PreRender event
14. Master page controls Unload event
15. Content page controls Unload event
16. Master page Unload event
17. Content page Unload event

Comment: I have a similar tacked up on mine...29 events though...mabye I'll post it...

Comment: I looked through mine, it has the ~Complete, ~OnBubble events.  Honestly haven't really needed to know about these, so this is a pretty complete list as well.

Answer (score 7):

This is the "original" MSDN overview. Pretty good:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227435.aspx

Honestly, you shouldn't need our help to find these things. Try Google.

Comment: I agree Tor, google can answer this question well.  However, having all this information in a single location is also very beneficial for all involved.

Comment: Yeah, I'm all for google as well, but a collection of everything in one thread relating to this topic?  Not bad...

Answer (score 6):

This diagram is specifically helpful in determining the order of events, but doesn't elaborate on them in any detail.

[image: ASP.NET Page Lifecycle]

[Original link](http://web.archive.org/web/20140605132938/http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/o_aspnet_page_lifecycle.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer the Page lifecycle question but this covers the Global event lifecycle with events like BeginRequest and EndRequest. It's good to understand how those work in relation to Pages.

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5771721.html