# Asp.net "Global" variables

Tags: .net, asp.net, postback, page-lifecycle

I'm writing a page in ASP.NET and am having problems following the cycle of initialization on postbacks:

I have (something akin to) the following:

```
public partial class MyClass : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    String myString = "default";

    protected void Page_Init(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        myString = Request["passedString"];
        //note that I've tried to set the default here in Init on NULL...
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
         if(!Postback)
         {
             //code that uses myString....
         }
         else
         {
            //more code that uses myString....
         }
    }
}
```

And what's happening is that my code picks up the "passedString" just fine, but for some reason, on postback, it resets to the default value - even if I put the assignment of the default in the Page_Init code... which makes me wonder what's going on..

Any help?

Comment: Is passedString a form value or querystring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class member variables do not live on once the response is sent to the browser.  Try using the Session object instead:

```
public partial class MyClass : System.Web.UI.Page
{    

    protected void Page_Init(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["myString"] = Request["passedString"];
        //note that I've tried to set the default here in Init on NULL...
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
         string myString = (string) Session["myString"];

         if(!Postback)
         {
             // use myString retrieved from session here
         }
         else
         {
            //more code that uses myString....
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: "our class member variables do not live on once the response is sent to the browser."  Put another way:  each postback is working with a NEW instance of your page class.

Answer (score 3):

I feel your pain Matt.  I asked a similar question a little while ago:

For a further understanding of the Page Life Cycle check out this question: [What is the 'page lifecycle' of an ASP.NET WebForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597042/what-is-the-page-lifecycle-of-an-asp-net-webform)

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but it was VERY useful information. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance (even if I don't get the accepted answer!)