# New to C# and trying to use a global variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to use global variables in C#?  I'm coming from mainly a PHP background so variables are either accessible everywhere or just a `global` definition away.

My main issue is I have a `User` class that I built myself to wrap around the current `users` table on my company's database.  I am defining it in the MasterPage but can't seem to access it from the actual pages (I don't know if there's a better word to describe them but they are the pages that inherit the styles and format from the MasterPage)

Any general tips or implementation practices for me?

**EDIT**: here's some code snippets of what I'm trying to do:

*Site.master.cs*

```
public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public User user = new User();
}
```

*logout.aspx*

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="logout.aspx.cs" Inherits="logout" %>
<%@ MasterType  virtualPath="~/Site.master"%>
```

*logout.aspx.cs*

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        User user = Master.user;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible per different recommnedations (and warnings) below. If you do choose to use globals I suggest doing so just to get moving forward but refactoring them out as soon as possible.

Comment: Don't think your problem is global variables or not. Rather how to get to data in your masterpage from your page instance.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is impossible. It is possible to create singletons or public static classes, but this is bad practice.

C# was designed for object oriented programming. If you haven't written programs using object oriented paradigm before it can be a bit hard to switch to it in the beginning. OOP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) is built on three main concepts: inheritance, polymorphism and encapsulation.

You can defined classed apart of the pages/masterpages, it is good practice to define them in the App_Code folder.

Comment: Just to add to @Andrew Bezzub's answer - public static classes are usually used to declare global consts, not to keep global state. If you need global state, use a singleton.

Answer (score 2):

Have a public static class and declare public static member variables.

That's what I do when I need some globals, though I try to avoid using them when I can.

Answer (score 2):

If `Page` is inheriting from `MasterPage`, then make `User` property protected in `MasterPage` and it will be visible to `Page`.

Answer (score 2):

The Master page class can be accessible to the pages that use it by setting the MasterPageClass in your .aspx page like so:

```
<%@ MasterType TypeName="MyTypeName" VirtualPath="~/MasterPageName.master" %>
```

It sounds to me like you may just need to put your code in a slightly different place. A typical User class would be accessible to your project through a stand-alone class, and not bundled into a master page or a master type.

I might suggest that you add your User class into a new classfile in the /AppCode directory of your project instead, (User.cs). That would let you have access to it from your pages without having to muck with the MasterType.

Comment: Yes I have User.cs in /App_Code (vs suggested I put it there so I thought WHY THE HELL NOT) -- but I need to define it somewhere (I thought in the MasterPage) as `User current_user = new User();` and then try to get at `current_user` from all the actual pages

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690452/asp-net-global-variables/690485#690485)** question.  Non-static class-level variables do no persist once the response is sent to the browser.  This is because each Page object is going to be a new instance of the class, not the same one from your last request.

Use the "Session" property instead as I show in the link.

Answer (score 1):

Is your problem, from your page, get to data stored in the masterpage (assuming we're talking about the ASP.Net MasterPage mechanism here)?

If so, you should look at [strongly-typed access to masterpages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx). Basically, what you do is create a public property in your MasterPage class. Then, in your Page, declare the MasterPageFile and MasterType, like this:

```
public partial class MasterPage
{
    public User CurrentUser{...}
}
```

In your page aspx, declare to use the masterpage and which master type to use.

```
<%@ Page  masterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"%>
<%@ MasterType  virtualPath="~/MasterPage.master"%>
```

You will then be able to access the property from within your page class like this:

```
var user = Master.CurrentUser;
```

Then, for the question on where to initialize the `CurrentUser` object, look at [the list of page lifecycle events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx). As you can see, MasterPage.Init fires *before* Page.Init and MasterPage.Load fires *before* Page.Load. You can use either MP.Init or MP.Load to make sure the data is ready for when the page events fire, though Init is preferred.

Comment: Peter I added a bunch of code snippets to my question, any ideas?  I think you are closest to knowing what I am TRYING to do

Comment: You're on the right track. But  `CodeFile="logout.aspx.cs" Inherits="logout"` doesn't look right for a page called `_Default`. Cut-n-paste error?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least a couple different ways to achieve what you want:

1. Use the [Application object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.application.aspx) - It can be used to store things globally and is part of ASP.Net.
2. Use [static classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28VS.80%29.aspx) - This is another option for creating a singleton.