# asp.net on page load what is the order of events?

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the ‘page lifecycle’ of an ASP.NET WebForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597042/what-is-the-page-lifecycle-of-an-asp-net-webform)

when i am opening an asp.net page, what is the order of the events like PreInit, etc that goes on?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597042/what-is-the-page-lifecycle-of-an-asp-net-webform

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) page has a good explanation.

To summarize:

- PreInit
- Init
- InitComplete
- PreLoad
- Load
- Control events
- LoadComplete
- PreRender
- SaveStateComplete
- Render
- Unload

Answer (score 3):

Seriously?  Just because StackOverflow is a fabulous site, doesn't mean it should be the first place you go every time... :P

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: Why not? Who are you to dictate what a person should or shouldn't do on the free platforms? Let's not ridicule people who don't do as we do.