# How does an aspx page is execute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, clr, execution, page-lifecycle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the 'page lifecycle' of an ASP.NET WebForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597042/what-is-the-page-lifecycle-of-an-asp-net-webform)

I have studied a lot of article on execution process in .net. What i found is that

Language code(C#,vb, j# etc.) ----> language compiler ---> MSIL code -----> 
now this MSIL code is processed by just-in-time which is inside CLR

this process is okay for class library execution or windows app or console app but in asp.net we have a .aspx page + a code behind (c#, vb etc.)...In that case how this execution process takes place ?

Comment: From the [faq] - "*Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.*"  This type of question is not really a good fit for this site.  There are plenty of books / article / resources out there to learn about this topic.  Of course, that's all just my opnion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET will process your ASPX and code-behind file like this:

1. Load ASPX from disk
2. Parse ASPX code into a code-dom that can be edited through extensibility hooks
3. Save that code into a C# file on disk
4. Use csc.exe to compile this code into an assembly. Everything in your /bin folder will be available as a reference.
5. Load the assembly.
6. Load all bin assemblies.
7. Invoke the rendering code inside the freshly compiled assembly. This will start the usual process of JITing and executing.

Comment: i think there must be a compiler to process aspx pages but you are saying that both aspx and c sharp code goes to csc.exe...please clarify

Comment: I improved the answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: He does have the clarification here - an ASPX file is converted to C# along with the code behind (both are two partial classes forming a single complete class). Then the compiler is used to create the IL code.

Comment: The generated class from the ASPX file inherits the class in CodeBehind. All code blocks, Eval/Bind expressions, Resource expressions,  declared in markup won't be accessible from code behind (go in that generated class).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bit too much to go into detail here, but you will want to look up the ASP.Net Page Lifecycle:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Additional info as suggested by commenters:
Before the actual execution, IIS compiles the code in both the page and its code behind or retrieves the compiled code from a compilation cache (ASP.Net dynamic compilation); more info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx

Comment: The page lifecycle is not the compilation lifecycle.

Comment: @dirk - usr is right...this is not answer of my question

Comment: The compilation life cycle can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx) (in the section bearing that name).

Comment: absolutely agreed, the question is about the execution but there may be some confusion there.