# How does ASP.NET load pages when using MasterPage.master for a project?

Tags: asp.net

The Links.aspx is based MasterPage.master.

A:  What is the loading order among MasterPage.master, MasterPage.master.cs, Links.aspx and Links.aspx.cs ?

B:  What is the loading order among  jquery-3.6.3.min.js, TodoA(),  base.js and TodoB(）?

**MasterPage.master**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="LinkTabs.MasterPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">  
    <script type="text/javascript" src='jquery-3.6.3.min.js'></script>   
   ...
</html>
```

**MasterPage.master.cs**

```
namespace LinkTabs
{
    public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TodoA()
        }
    }
}
```

**Links.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="Open A List Of URLs" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Links.aspx.cs" Inherits="LinkTabs.Links" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="LinkTabs.App_MyCode.BLL" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">       
    
    <script src='~/Js/base.js'></script>
    ...
</asp:Content>
```

**Links.aspx.cs**

```
namespace LinkTabs
{
    public partial class Links : System.Web.UI.Page
    {       

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              TodoB()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: for the first question, roughly been discussed on [another qa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/597051) the official docs can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178472(v=vs.100)).

Comment: `TodoA` and `TodoB` runs **before** any javascript as they ran on the server. `base.js` depends on where you put your placeholder for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a master page, then the page load event of the child page fires, and then the master page load event fires WHEN you navigate to that page.

Now, if you click a button on the child page, then again the pattern is quite much the same.

Child page load event fires.

Master page load event fires.

Child page button click event code stub fires.

So, keep in mind that for any post-back, button click etc. on the child page, then the child page load event fires, then master page, then your child button click code stub.

So:

```
 Child page load event->Master Page Load event->child page code stub
```

As a general rule, we often really don't care much about the above.

However, if  that child page hides/shows a menu item, then as above shows, the code for the child page will run AFTER the master page code has run, and thus you not in general see the menu items (the master page menu) change.

So, above suggests and hints that code to hide/show or control menu items should be placed in the master page load event.